# Disable Spotlight indexing, save battery life

Tags: snow-leopard, spotlight, battery, power-management

I am using my laptop with *very limited* battery availability. I need to save as much battery as possible.

- I would like to disable Spotlight indexing, how do I do that?
- What else should I disable, even temporarily, to truly **maximise** savings? Services? Unix daemons? Is there a list?

Thanks.

PS I have already:

- dimmed keyboard backlight (on a MacBook Pro)
- switched off WiFi (apart from this post)
- dimmed screen backlight
- disabled discrete graphics
- closed non-vital apps

Comment: If you want both questions answered, you should split them up in different posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the immediate way is:

```
sudo mdutil -i off /
```

from the command line (you will have to enter your admin password) to stop indexing immediately.

You might also want to add the following step:

```
sudo vim /etc/hostconfig
```

(you might want to use a different editor than vim, YMMV)

Then, navigate to the entry

```
SPOTLIGHT=-YES-
```

and change it to

```
SPOTLIGHT=-NO-
```

SAVE the changes the exit the file.  BTW, have a look at [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/) on how to change the battery, it seems you could have much better use of the laptop that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll really save anything battery-wise, but you might try `defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool YES` and then using `cmd-K` to quit the Finder.